# use elastic-apm jar java agent with aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-apm

as of now elastic beanstalk allows to upload a single jar file for deployment.

i want to run custom script as per the below command for starting the application.

```
sudo java -Dlogging.file=/home/ec2-user/server.log -Xmx8192m -javaagent:/home/ec2-user/server/elastic-apm-agent-1.12.0.jar 
-Delastic.apm.service_name=service-name
-Delastic.apm.application_packages=com.demo
-Delastic.apm.server_urls=xxx
-Delastic.apm.secret_token=XXX 
-jar $server_name-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
--spring.profiles.active=prod
```

not sure if we can do it with some config file to specify the path of the java agent if we know the path of the java agent jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EB configuration > environment properties, you'd have to set `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-javaagent:/home/ec2-user/server/elastic-apm-agent-1.12.0.jar` and the rest of your -D and -Xmx properties in `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

You will also need to download the agent using ebextensions config:

```
files:
  "/home/ec2-user/server/elastic-apm-agent-1.12.0.jar":
    mode: "000444"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: "https://<host>/elastic-apm-agent-1.12.0.jar"
```